# Deploying a React-Bootstrap project to IIS - Admin & Client run only use port 80

Tags: reactjs, iis, deployment, port

I have website include admin and client, I've created 2 project for website (admin & client) form Reactjs-Bootstrap, backend O use Flask of Python. But I'm deployment with strict article:

- Deploy with IIS 10.0, windows server 2016
- Only User 80 & 1521

Port 1521 I used for backend.

Now, port 80 I will run client and admin. I tried add application but not working (http://domain/admin. error 500)

[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/a3fkl.png)

Comment: I'm not sure if I understand your question correctly. But port only can be set at site level, when you add application under website, IIS allow you set alias for it but not port. In url, port is following domain name not any part of uri. So  you can not set different port for different applications under a site.

Comment: Please clarify your specific problem or provide additional details to highlight exactly what you need. As it's currently written, it's hard to tell exactly what you're asking.